# Lines drawn randomly

Tags: java, user-interface, lwjgl

I got a weird bug. I'm currently doing a video game in java with LWJGL to implement the graphics. I can do almost everything but I discover something very strange : 95% of the times, my GUI looks exactly like it must do and the 5% remaining some of the lines are not drawn.
I checked if the part of the code that must draw the line is read and it is. So I just can't figure out what happens. Do you ave any idea how to fix this ?

Thank you !!

Edit :
I just figure out that I didn't explain ou anything... So to make everything easier, I tried to implement GUI element like those of the awt package but in LWJGL. Untill now, I have just implemented a Label, a ProgressBar, a Window and a MainPanel (to draw the background of my GUI).

As you can see below, the ProgressBar and the Label are put inside the Window that will manage everything, namely the position and the size of the element inside it. So, when I draw the window, I draw everything inside it at the same time : in my case, the ProgressBar and the Label. For the Label, it is all the time displayed but the ProgressBar not. Because I'm nearly sure that the bug must come from the drawing method of my ProgressBar, I had it at the end of the post.

This is the code of the class that will draw everything on the screen :
public class ConnectionDrawer implements InterfaceDrawer {

```
private boolean needUpdate = true;

private BlockingQueue<String> in; 

private ProgressBar bar;
private MainPanel background;
private Window load_window;
private Label text;

public ConnectionDrawer() {
    in = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();

    bar = new ProgressBar();
    bar.setBorderColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    bar.setBarColor(1.0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f);
    bar.setMaxValue(3);
    bar.setPadding(1);
    bar.setCurrentValue(0);
    ElementProperties prop_bar = new ElementProperties(
            ElementProperties.ABSOLUTE, ElementProperties.ABSOLUTE);
    prop_bar.setAbsoluteSize(280, 30);
    prop_bar.setAbsolutePosition(10, 40);

    text = new Label("Trying to connect to server...");
    text.setBorder(false);
    text.setSize(Label.MEDIUM);
    text.setColor(Color.white);
    text.setVerticalAlign(Label.TOP);
    text.setHorizontalAlign(Label.LEFT);
    ElementProperties prop_bar1 = new ElementProperties(
            ElementProperties.ABSOLUTE, ElementProperties.ABSOLUTE);
    prop_bar1.setAbsoluteSize(280, 30);
    prop_bar1.setAbsolutePosition(10, 5);

    background = new MainPanel();
    background
            .setBackground(GraphicController.getTextureLoader().cloudy_background);

    load_window = new Window();
    load_window.setBackgroundColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 0.5f);
    load_window.enableBackground(true);
    load_window.enableBorder(true);
    load_window.setBorderColor(0, 0, 0);
    load_window.addComponent(bar, prop_bar);
    load_window.addComponent(text, prop_bar1);
}

@Override
public void draw() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    GraphicController.getWindow().initGL2D();
    GL11.glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    if (needUpdate) {
        load_window.setDimension(300, 80);
        load_window.setPosition(Data.getActifResolution().getWidth() - 310,
                Data.getActifResolution().getHeight() - 90);
        needUpdate = false;
    }

    background.draw();
    GraphicController.getTextureLoader().white_text.bind();
    load_window.draw();

}

public void updateNeeded() {
    this.needUpdate = true;
}

@Override
public void checkKeyBoard() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (Display.isCloseRequested())
        GraphicController.getWindow().changeDone();
}

@Override
public void postMessage(Object obj) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    in.add((String) obj);
}

}
```

and this is the code of the ProgressBar class that is not drawn every times :

```
public void draw() {
    System.out.println("Progress draw");

    //System.out.println(b_r+";"+b_g+";"+b_b+";"+b_a);
    GL11.glColor4f(b_r, b_g, b_b, b_a);
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_LINES);
    {
        GL11.glVertex2f(x, y);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x + width, y);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x + width, y);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x + width, y + height);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x + width, y + height);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x, y + height);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x, y + height);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x, y);
    }
    GL11.glEnd();

    float ratio;
    if (max == 0 || current == 0) {
        System.out.println("Progress draw end");
        return;
    } else if (max == 0) {
        ratio = 0;
    } else {
        ratio = ((float) current) / ((float) max);
    }

    GL11.glColor4f(i_r, i_g, i_b, i_a);
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
    {
        GL11.glVertex2f(x + pad_inside, y + pad_inside + 1);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x - 1 + ratio * width - pad_inside, y + pad_inside
                + 1);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x - 1 + ratio * width - pad_inside, y + height
                - pad_inside - 1);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x + pad_inside, y + height - pad_inside - 1);
    }
    GL11.glEnd();
}
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem, this will reduce the guess work and produce better response

Comment: is it possible you are drawing line outside screen/viewport or bellow other object which is displayed on screen

Comment: @MadProgrammer I edit my post to add the code of the classes where the problem takes place.

Comment: @user902383 I checked and the line are always inside the window :-\

Answer (score 0):

So after multiple check, I could identify the source of the error. In fact, it comes from the class that displays text on screen. I think that all I need to do is to disable the GL_TEXTURE_2D option after displaying text.